# Installing npm packages from multiple registries

Tags: npm

Working on a project where I need to install `npm` packages from several registries - the default `npm` registry and several custom registries.

My existing solution is to use `npm` `scripts` to break the install into steps which use the `--registry` flag. Something like this:

```
"install-pkg1":   "npm install pkg1 --registry https://pkg1.domain.com",
"install-pkg2":   "npm install pkg2 --registry https://pkg2.domain.com",
"install-custom": "npm install && npm run install-pkg1 && npm run install-pkg2"
```

Then use `npm run install-custom` in place of `npm install` to install all the dependencies.

Is there a more preferred method for installing packages from multiple registries?

As noted in the comments below, there is a [discussion on Github about this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/100#issuecomment-254076807).

Comment: A link back to github will help visibility: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/100#issuecomment-254076807

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much one of the reasons for [npm ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html). The registries and versions will be defined there so you shouldnt need to do anything crazy to get them all from their corresponding registries. Also, this can kind of be accomplished [with scopes](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes), where you associate a registry with a scope, but this requires you publishing the packages scoped as whatever. [more info on associating registry with scopes](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope)

Comment: I realize this is an old question and npm has changed a lot since then but I thought I would add some findings from doing my own research on this issue lately, which is how I came across the question in the first place

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but I just wanted to point out that answering this old question, for me at least, allowed to spend less time on a search engine. IMO you shouldn't hesitate to do that again on other old questions, if the opportunity comes up